# Best way to sort large amounts of similar variables?

Tags: php, database, pdo

I'm going to be getting **LARGE** amounts of simple data.

It will basically be on a single webpage, and the user will correspond to which (identical) iFrame should be loaded (EXTERNAL - (site.com/this) / (site.com/that)) - where this/that are the same, but have a different name in the page.

Would it be best to insert them into a database, and withdraw them by something like this? (pseudo-code)

```
// username to be replaced by a parameter
$query = "select url from table where user = 'username'";

//run query against the database
$url = $query[url];
echo "<iframe src='".$url."' />";
```

or would it be best to do some very basic PHP (I'm expecting thousands of combinations)

```
if($_POST['query'] == 'John Doe') { $url = 'site.com/this' }
if($_POST['query'] == 'Jane Flo') { $url = 'site.com/that' }
```

In either scenario, somebody will be submitted a very simple form with first/last name, or maybe also a city/state (unsure).

I'm thinking the database would be "better", but the strict db-less PHP seems easier to manage, but does it cause issues?

Comment: could you tell us how much it's large? 1,000 or 1,000,000?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to store this in a database yes. SQL databases generally sort anyway, so sorting large amounts of data is very cheap.

With MySQL, this sort of query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY sort;
```

It's unclear what exactly you're doing, but generally external sites in an iframe are a no-no, because they are unmanageable, you cannot access them with JavaScript, or any other means for that matter.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a partnership program and it's what they told me to do lol. I've considered just a straight link to their site, but that's still a `$this` means load `$that` scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In any case you don't want to store them on the database:

```
$data['John Doe'] = 'site.com/this';
$data['Jane Flo'] = 'site.com/that';

echo '<iframe src="' . $data[$_POST['query']] . '" />';
```